# FluentNhibernate and NHibernate 3.2

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Is there a FluentNHibernate release that is compiled against NHibernate 3.2?
If not, will using assmeblyBinding from 3.1 to 3.2 work?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using NuGet and install the latest FNH package it is compatible with NH 3.2

http://nuget.org/List/Packages/FluentNHibernate/1.3.0.717

You'll need to install it via the command line in NuGet but this is what I've done and it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of any new release. FNH 1.2 won't work with NH3.2 out of the box. you need to setup the binding in your app.config like this:

```
    <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="NHibernate" publicKeyToken="aa95f207798dfdb4" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.2.0.4000" newVersion="3.2.0.4000" />
    </dependentAssembly>
```

FYI: i am using this setup

Comment: Does the same goes to the NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu proxy factory?

Comment: Bytocode provider should be transparent to FHN so it should work. With FNH you just configure it like: .ProxyFactoryFactory("NHibernate.Bytecode.DefaultProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate")

Comment: If you are using NuGet and install the latest FNH package it is compatible with NH 3.2

Comment: @Cole W: if this is true i think you should set this as normal answer for sternr to accept as the correct one